System.CalloutException: PKIX path building failed: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
Sorry for the unexpected appearance, I saw your profile on the forum dealing with the error:
System.CalloutException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
I've been trying to deal with this error for several weeks. I'm going to tell you about my situation in case something occurs to you and I will be eternally grateful :)
I have an Apex class that wants to make an http POST request:
public String ALF_getTicket() {
HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
req.setClientCertificateName('prealhacenaicex');
String BaseURLAuth = https://pre-alhacena.icex.es/alfresco/api/-default-/public/authentication/versions/1/tickets //custom setting
req.setEndpoint(BaseURLAuth);
req.setMethod('POST');
req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
String userId = //custom setting
String password = //custom setting
Map<String, String> body = new Map<String, String>();
body.put('userId', userId);
body.put('password', password);

String jsonString = JSON.serialize(body);
req.setBody(jsonString);
req.setTimeout(120000); // milisegundos

Http http = new Http();
HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);

// Almacena el ID del ticket en una variable
String ALF_ticket;

if (res.getStatusCode() == 201) {
// Parsea el JSON de la respuesta
Map<String, Object> jsonResponse = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(res.getBody());
Map<String, Object> entry = (Map<String, Object>) jsonResponse.get('entry');
ALF_ticket = (String) entry.get('id');
} else {
throw new UCMException('Error excepcion:' + req);
}

// Devuelve el ID del ticket almacenado
return ALF_ticket;
}

When running it from anonymous I get the System.CalloutException error.
To deal with it, I obtained the SSL Certificate from the endpoint server which is a CA certificate, signed by GoDaddy, as it did not work I still followed this guide:
https://santiagoibarra.medium.com/install-a-ca-certificate-used-by-your-domain-in-salesforce-69c7e00a4247
Therefore, I obtained the intermediate certificate and the root certificate from the SSL certificate of the website and downloaded both in .crt. Once I have all three, I generate a new file called ChainCertificate.crt with this order:
1.SSL
2. Intermediate
3. Root
I saved it as and updated the CA certificate in Certificate and Key Management. It still doesn't work and I can't think of anything anymore.
I checked my custom salsforc url (+/cacerts.jsp) for the CAs and the certificate provider is included.
I also used OpenSSL:

I also tried the same thing but without adding root, knowing that SF has many of these roots by default, but neither. I don't know what else to do and I don't know anyone who has had this problem. I don't know if reading this you detect something that I haven't done or done wrong, or any alternative solution.
Any advice you can give me is sure to be of great help.
All the best.

https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html?d=pre-alhacena.icex.es will show you that icex.es is not sending the entire cert chain to Salesforce. You won't be able to fix this on the client (your SF org) side - contact icex.es owners.

First of all, thank you for your response. Looking at the url you sent me, some doubts arise.
1-. If the chain is incomplete, why does OpenSSL give OK to the certificate?
2-. To obtain the certificates, I accessed https://pre-alhacena.icex.es/ and in the browser console under security I saw that there were three certificates. How can I know which one is missing?
3-. If you get the missing one, would you add it concatenated to the other certificates and upload it to salesforce?
Thank you very much in advance.


Unclear what you're doing with OpenSSL. by 2. The intermediate one is missing. 3. No, that won't help you. The endpoint needs to return the chain. The only cert that can be "skipped" is the root because SF has roots it trusts.


1I used the command: openssl verify -CAfile gdroot-g2.crt -untrusted gdig2.crt.pem prealhacenaicex.crt to verify that the string was correct, then I concatenated them and updated it in salesforce. 2How do you know that one is missing? From the browser console I see three: SSL->pre-alhacena.icex.es Inter->Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2 and root->Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
3I don't understand why it won't help me, if it is an intermediate I would have to add it, right? At this point, what is the solution to the problem?that pre-alhacena.icex.es return the entire chain?


Not the same thing as what is done by a web-based SSL client in Salesforce. that's why SSL Labs check is what you're after. 2. From the SSL Labs check. 3. Open a ticket with SF support, they might explain it to you.


thank you very much for your help. I opened the ticket to Salesforce and they were the ones who recommended me to download the certificates and concatenate them. To understand my problem well, and to be able to provide them with information, what would you say is my incidence? Lack of any certificates? Do you think the provider of https://pre-alhacena.icex.es/ could do something?

Support gave you incorrect advice, it happens. pre-alhacena.icex.es needs to send the entire chain (up to root) and its root needs to be trusted by Salesforce. See https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000385468&type=1 .

Understood. Sorry for my ignorance but then I should talk to the administrator of pre-alhacena.icex.es and how do I tell him to send me the entire chain?

I have asked them to install all the certificates again and it works now. You were right, it was the other side's fault. Thank you very much for your help.
